# Camera Contents in Wallpaper Surface

Tags: android, service, camera, android-camera, live-wallpaper

I am working on an application in ANDROID in which I need to create a service (A wallpaper service) which executes in background and displays the live contents of Camera on the Wallpaper surface.

I have tried a lot but unfortunately unable to reach the target. And Every time I tried, I concluded that wallpaper surface may not support camera view. But then how one of the application in market using the same concept.

Can any one help me out for the same. The reference we can say that I need something like like " **Camera through wallpaper** " Application which is already in market.

Thank You